# Copy Selected Files to another folder via the Context Menu

Tags: arrays, powershell

I'm trying to copy selected items in a folder and paste them into a different folder via a script shortcut in the context menu.[image: Screenshot of Context Menu]

This script is a shortcut to Powershell.exe that calls the .ps1 to execute. Technically, the script works, but it's only copying the file that is actually right-clicked instead of the group of selected files. In the screenshot, if I selected both "Saved Pictures" and "Screenshots", but right-clicked "Saved Pictures", it would *only* copy "Saved Pictures" even though "Screenshots" is also selected.

```
Function Collection{

    #Selects the Item's Current Path
    param($SourceFile)

    #Copy the selected file to the Document Collection folder
    Copy-Item $SourceFile -Destination (New-Item "$Env:UserName\My Documents\temp" -Type Directory -Force) -Recurse -Force
}

Collection $args[0]
```

I guess my main question for you guys is **How do I copy all selected files instead of just the file that is clicked?**

Comment: Maybe the `args` array holds other items ? You only use the first one, `args[0]`. What's in `args[1]`, for instance ? And why not add the desired folder in this specific context menu, instead of a script ?

Comment: "And why not add the desired folder in this specific context menu"

To be honest, that never occurred to me and I'm not sure how I'll see how to do this and if it solved my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hit the `Windows` and `R` key to open the `Run` dialog, type this and hit `Enter` :

```
shell:sendto
```

You can add a shortcut to your destination folder in the opened system folder to add it to the **Send to** list

This seems to fit what you want to achieve here.

Source : [howtogeek](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/customize-the-windows-vista-send-to-menu/)

Comment: Not sure why this was rated down because it applied to the last comment I made. Thanks for the information.

Comment: I created a Group Policy to push this out and it seems to be working great. Thanks!